# How to make resize cursors show up for a floating non-activating panel?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nspanel

I have a floating NSPanel that is non-activating, i.e. its `styleMask` contains the `NSNonactivatingPanelMask` flag. Since this panel never becomes active, the system does not show the usual resize cursors when getting close to one of the panel's edges.

Is there a way to get those resize cursors to show up for a non-activating panel? E.g. the system's font panel pulls this off somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[NSFontPanel sharedFontPanel].styleMask == (NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask | NSUtilityWindowMask)`. However, it shows resize indicators even if you add `NSNonactivatingPanelMask`.

When you set `[NSFontPanel sharedFontPanel].hidesOnDeactivate = NO` and activate another app, resize indicators stop working. This is by design, because even regular inactive windows cannot be resized.

So maybe you are trying to add resize indicators when the panel-owning app is inactive. Just a thought.

Comment: Good point, the app is indeed inactive. I guess there is no way to make the system show the resize cursors for the floating window while the app is inactive...? :)

Comment: I assume no, you should adjust design and user experience or implement resize indicators using `NSTrackingArea`. This is definitely possible :)